# Как обернуть текст (код страны) в тег <p> в данном скрипте?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, виджет

Есть выпадающий список с кодами стран на `JQuery`. Но код страны отображается без тега, просто внутри `<div>`. Из-за этого не могу позицию символа поставить так, как мне нужно. Т.е. код страны отображается под флагом при загрузке страницы, а нужно, чтобы он был справа. 
После клика по любой стране в списке, код страны отображается уже справа, а не снизу. Уже все перепробовал, не получается поставить в нужную позицию код страны.
Вот [ссылка](http://jakulov.ru/blog/2014/phonecode_widget) на полный код с описанием.

Сам код:

```
var countryCache;
var countryRequesting = false;
(function($) {
    $.widget('custom.phonecode', {
        data: [],
        container: null,
        prefixField: null,
        searchTimeout: null,
        suggestTimeout: null,
        hideTimeout: null,
        options: {
            default_prefix: '',
            prefix: '',
            preferCo: 'росси'
        },
        _create: function() {
            this._loadData();
            this.element.wrap('<div class="country-phone">');
            var container = this.element.parent('.country-phone');
            var selector = $('<div class="country-phone-selector"><div class="country-phone-selected"></div><div class="country-phone-options"></div></div>');
            $(selector).prependTo(container);

            var prefixName = this.options.prefix ?
                this.options.prefix : '__phone_prefix';
            var hidden = $('<input type="hidden" name="'+ prefixName +'" value="'+ this.options.default_prefix +'">');
            $(hidden).appendTo(container);

            this.container = container;
            this.prefixField = hidden;
        },

        _loadData : function() {
            var self = this;
            if(!countryCache && !countryRequesting) {
                countryRequesting = $.getJSON('countries.json', {})
                    .done(function(json) {
                        self.data = json;
                        countryCache = self.data;
                        self._initSelector();
                    })
                    .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
                        //alert(status + ' ' + error);
                        self.data = countries;
                        countryCache = self.data;
                        self._initSelector();
                    });
            }
            else if(countryCache) {
                this.data = countryCache;
                self._initSelector();
            }
            else if(countryRequesting) {
                countryRequesting.done(function(json) {
                    self.data = json;
                    countryCache = self.data;
                    self._initSelector();
                });
            }
        },

        _initSelector: function() {
            var options = this.container.find('.country-phone-options');
            var selector = this.container.find('.country-phone-selected');
            var selected = null;
            var self = this;
            var searchInput = $('<input type="text" class="country-phone-search" value="">');
            $(searchInput).appendTo(options);
            var searchLabel = $('<label class="country-phone-search-label">Введите страну</label>');
            $(searchLabel).on('click',function(){
                $(this).hide();
                $(searchInput).focus();
            }).insertAfter(searchInput);
            $(searchLabel).hide().show();
            $(searchInput).bind('keyup', function(e){
                if(self.suggestTimeout) {
                    window.clearTimeout(self.suggestTimeout);
                }
                var input = this;
                var ev = e;
                self.suggestTimeout = window.setTimeout(function(){
                    var text = $(input).val().toLowerCase();
                    self.suggestCountry(text);
                    if(ev.keyCode == 40) {
                        self._moveSuggestDown(options);
                    }
                    if(ev.keyCode == 38) {
                        self._moveSuggestUp(options);
                    }
                    if(ev.keyCode == 13) {
                        var hovered = $(options).find('.hovered:visible');
                        if(hovered.length) {
                            if(!$(hovered).hasClass('country-phone-search')) {
                                self.setElementSelected(hovered);
                                self._toggleSelector();
                            }
                        }
                        ev.stopPropagation();
                        ev.preventDefault();
                    }
                }, 100);

                if($(this).val() == '') {
                    $(searchLabel).show();
                }
                else {
                    $(searchLabel).hide();
                }

            }).bind('keypress', function(e){
                if(e.keyCode == 13) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
            });

            for(var i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
                if(i == 0) {
                    selected = this.data[i];
                }
                var country = this.data[i];
                var prefCountry = country.co;

                var option = $('<div data-phone="'+
                    country.ph + '" data-co="'+ prefCountry.toLowerCase() +'"' +
                    ' class="country-phone-option"><span>'+ country.ph +'<img src="blank.gif" class="flag flag-'+
                    country.co +
                    '"></span>'+ country.na +'</div>'
                );
                $(option).appendTo(options);
                if(this.options.preferCo && (this.options.preferCo != undefined)) {
                    if(prefCountry == this.options.preferCo) {
                        selected = country;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if(country.ph == this.options.default_prefix) {
                        selected = country;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(selected) {
                this.container.find('.country-phone-selected')
                    .html('<img src="blank.gif" class="flag flag-'+ selected.co +'">+'+ selected.ph);
            }
            $(selector).bind('click', function(e){
                self._toggleSelector();
            });
            $(options).find('.country-phone-option').bind('click', function(){
                self.setElementSelected(this);
                self._toggleSelector();
            });
            $(options).hover(function(){
                if(self.hideTimeout) {
                    window.clearTimeout(self.hideTimeout);
                }
            }, function(){
                var select = this;
                self.hideTimeout = window.setTimeout(self._mouseOverHide, 1000, select, self);
            });

            this._initInput();
        },

        _mouseOverHide: function(select, self) {
            if(self.container) {
                var searchInput = self.container.find('.country-phone-search');
                if(!$(searchInput).is(':focus')) {
                    $(select).hide();
                }
                else {
                    self.hideTimeout = window.setTimeout(self._mouseOverHide, 1000, select, self);
                }
            }
        },

        _moveSuggestDown: function(options) {
            var select = null;
            var hovered = $(options).find('.hovered:visible');
            if(hovered.length) {
                var next = $(hovered).next(':visible');
                if(next.length) {
                    select = next;
                }
                else {
                    next = $(hovered).nextUntil(':visible').last().next();
                    if(next.length) {
                        select = next;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(!select) {
                select = $(options).find('.country-phone-option:visible').first();
            }
            if(select) {
                $(options).find('.country-phone-option').add('.country-phone-search').removeClass('hovered');
                $(select).addClass('hovered');
            }
        },

        _moveSuggestUp: function(options) {
            var select = null;
            var hovered = $(options).find('.hovered:visible');
            if(hovered.length) {
                var next = $(hovered).prev(':visible');
                if(next.length) {
                    select = next;
                }
                else {
                    next = $(hovered).prevUntil(':visible').last().prev();
                    if(next.length) {
                        select = next;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(!select) {
                select = $(options).find('.country-phone-option:visible').last();
            }
            if(select) {
                $(options).find('.country-phone-option').add('.country-phone-search').removeClass('hovered');
                $(select).addClass('hovered');
            }
        },

        suggestCountry: function(text, checkCode) {
            var options = this.container.find('.country-phone-options');
            var self = this;
            $(options).find('.country-phone-option').each(function(){
                if(text) {
                    if(text == 'россия') {
                        text = 'росси';
                    }
                    var match = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
                    if(match.indexOf(text) >= 0) {
                        $(this).show();
                        if(checkCode && checkCode != undefined) {
                            var code = $(this).data('phone');
                            var selCode = self.prefixField.val();
                            if(selCode == code) {
                                self.setElementSelected(this);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        if(!checkCode) {
                            $(this).hide();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $(this).show();
                }
            });
        },

        _toggleSelector: function(){
            var options = this.container.find('.country-phone-options');
            if($(options).is(':visible')) {
                $(options).hide('fast');
                $(options).find('.country-phone-search').val('').blur();
                this.element.focus();
                this.suggestCountry('');
            }
            else {
                $(options).show('fast');
                window.setTimeout(function(){
                    var searchInp = $(options).find('.country-phone-search');
                    $(searchInp).val('').focus();
                }, 300);
            }
        },

        setElementSelected: function(el) {
            var selector = this.container.find('.country-phone-selected');
            var code = $(el).data('phone');
            var sel = $(el).html();
            sel = sel.split('</span>');
            $(selector).html(sel[0] +'</span>');
            this.prefixField.val(code);

            return code;
        },

        _initInput: function() {
            var self = this;
            this.element.bind('keyup', function(){
                var text = $(this).val();
                if(text.length > 1 && text[0] == '+') {
                    var code = text.substring(1);
                    if(self.searchTimeout) {
                        window.clearTimeout(self.searchTimeout);
                    }
                    var input = this;
                    window.setTimeout(function(){
                        var found = self.searchCountryCode(code);
                        if(found) {
                            text = $(input).val();
                            text = text.replace('+' + found, '');
                            $(input).val(text);
                        }
                    }, 1000);
                }
            });

            this.initInputVal();
        },

        initInputVal: function() {
            var text = this.element.val();
            var self = this;
            if(text.length > 1 && text[0] == '+') {
                for(var i = 6; i >= 1; i--) {
                    var code = text.substring(1, i);
                    var found = self.searchCountryCode(code);
                    if(found) {
                        text = this.element.val();
                        text = text.replace('+' + found, '');
                        this.element.val(text);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(text.length == 1 && text[0] == '+') {
                this.element.val('');
            }
        },

        searchCountryCode: function(code) {
            var options = this.container.find('.country-phone-options');
            var search = code;
            var self = this;
            var found = false;
            var foundItems = [];
            $(options).find('.country-phone-option').each(function(){
                if(search == $(this).data('phone')) {
                    foundItems.push({
                        co: $(this).data('co'),
                        el: this
                    });
                }
            });

            if(foundItems.length == 1) {
                found = self.setElementSelected(foundItems[0].el);
            }
            else if(foundItems.length > 1) {
                for(var i = 0; i < foundItems.length; i++) {
                    if(self.options.preferCo) {
                        if(self.options.preferCo == foundItems[i].co) {
                            found = self.setElementSelected(foundItems[i].el);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        found = self.setElementSelected(foundItems[i].el);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(!found) {
                    found = self.setElementSelected(foundItems[0].el);
                }
            }

            return found;
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: весь необходимый код должен быть _непосредственно_ в вопросе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как обернуть текст (код страны) в тег `<p>` в данном скрипте ?

Добавьте обертку `<p></p>` в код создание опции.

1. Добавьте обертку для выбора по умолчанию:

   ```
   if(selected) {
      this.container.find('.country-phone-selected')
           .html('<img src="blank.gif" class="flag flag-'+ selected.co+'">+'+ '<p>'+ selected.ph + '</p>');
   }
   ```
2. Добавьте обертку для `option` в `select`.
   При смене страны загружается выбранный `<option>`, который будет содержать код страны обернутый в `<p></p>`

   ```
       var option = $('<div data-phone="'+
                   country.ph + '" data-co="'+ prefCountry.toLowerCase() +'"' +
                   ' class="country-phone-option"><span>+<p>'+ country.ph +'</p><img src="blank.gif" class="flag flag-'+
                   country.co +
                   '"></span>'+ country.na +'</div>'
               );
   ```

P.S.: обратите внимание, что в данном примере обернут только код страны без знака `+`.